# Unable to use javascript on PHP Page

Tags: javascript, php

not sure if there's something wrong with this code but I was able to make it work on pure HTML Page but not when using the javascript(javascript:openDocument) on the PHP HTML Page.

```
<a id='edit' href='javascript:openDocument('asd.docx')' name='Btn1'>Edit</a>
```

Comment: `href='javascript:openDocument('asd.docx')'` ==> `href='javascript:openDocument(\'asd.docx\')'`. Notice `\'` escaping

Comment: Hi Thanks for responding, I tried it but it's not working too.. the error message that i'm getting when highlighting the hyper link is "javascript.openDocument(\" without the quotations.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<a id='edit' href="javascript:openDocument('asd.docx');" name='Btn1'>Edit</a>
```

Also prefer double quotes in HTML.

**For PHP:**

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:openDocument('asd.docx')\";>";
```

Comment: Are you just copying and pasting this straight into your PHP script? It needs to either be echoed or you need to break the script by using ?>, enter the html and then reopen the php script with <?php

Comment: If you want to add plain HTML in PHP then just close the PHP tag and put your plain HTML.

Comment: Hi mfisher91. Yes, I'm echoing it on PHP but it's still not working, the code I'm currently using is echo  "<a href='javascript:openDocument('asd.docx')>';. It's undoubtedly working If I change href to href="asd.docx"

Comment: echo "<a href=\"javascript:openDocument('asd.docx')\";>";

Comment: Thanks but it is still not working.. when I highlight the URL it display a message on the status bar of IE like this javascript:openDocument('asd.docx') - it's not opening when I click it.. it does nothing.. when there should be when I do it using HTML..

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in a comment, you need to overcome the problem of having two lots of single quotes in your href part. Why? When you get to the second ', it thinks you are ending. You can do this:

```
<a id="edit" href="javascript:openDocument('asd.docx');">
```